# Get the size of the files that consuming huge space using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, filesystems

How to get the size of the files, like `.mdf`,`.ldf` and other file extensions,in order to find out which file format is consuming huge space, using PowerShell.

Also I want to get the author of each of files that's `Last Modified By`.

I have tried to use cmdlet `Get-Item` or `Get-ChildItem` to extract the information of files present in the file system, like `D:\` or `E:\`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a cmdlet like `Get-Item` or `Get-ChildItem` to retrieve information about files from the file system, they return `FileInfo` objects, all of which have a `Length` property - the size (in bytes) of that file on the disk.

As an example, if you want to find the 10 largest files in a directory structure, you can use `Sort-Object` and `Select-Object`, like so:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Sort-Object Length -Descending| Select-Object FullName,Length -First 10
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how many `Mb` of a certain file type are in a folder or drive you can use the following commands:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\" -Filter "*.mdf" -Recurse | %{$_.Length} | measure -Sum | select -ExpandProperty Sum | %{"$($_/1024/1024) Mb"}
```

Just change the folder and `-Filter` parameter for each extension and you will get their amounts in `Mb` returned.

**Note:** Running this on a lager directory will take sometime to recurse through.